# Video: Embed a RTSP 3GP Quicktime seems to be impossible

Tags: video, streaming, quicktime, rtsp, 3gp

**Situation:** I want to embed this stream in my website:
[rtsp://v8.cache2.c.youtube.com/CiQLENy73wIaGwnUg6yvPB1bKxMYESARFEgGUghzdGFuZGFyZAw=/0/0/0/video.3gp](http://rtsp://v8.cache2.c.youtube.com/CiQLENy73wIaGwnUg6yvPB1bKxMYESARFEgGUghzdGFuZGFyZAw=/0/0/0/video.3gp)

**Problem:** All my tries to embed fail, only Quicktime logo shows up.

**Code:**

```
<object height="200" width="400" codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab" classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" id="qt">
<param value="rtsp://v8.cache2.c.youtube.com/CiQLENy73wIaGwnUg6yvPB1bKxMYESARFEgGUghzdGFuZGFyZAw=/0/0/0/video.3gp" name="src">
<param value="true" name="autoplay">
<param value="false" name="controller">
<embed height="200" width="400" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/" controller="false" autoplay="true" showlogo="false" kioskmode="true" qtsrc="rtsp://v8.cache2.c.youtube.com/CiQLENy73wIaGwnUg6yvPB1bKxMYESARFEgGUghzdGFuZGFyZAw=/0/0/0/video.3gp" scale="ASPECT" bgcolor="000000" src="rtsp://v8.cache2.c.youtube.com/CiQLENy73wIaGwnUg6yvPB1bKxMYESARFEgGUghzdGFuZGFyZAw=/0/0/0/video.3gp" name="player" id="player">
</object>
```

**Question:** What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

QuickTime is super picky about the CODECs it will play.  Use another media player.